# Filtering an array of objects from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects `lookups` and an array `filters`. Now I want to filter the array from an array of objects using the object attribute `name`.

I used `filter` and `some` but I could not get the expected result.

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

`[{id: 3, name: "Linkedin"}]`

```js
let lookups = [
{id: 1, name: "Twitter"},
{id: 2, name: "Facebook"},
{id: 3, name: "Linkedin"}
]

let filters = ["Facebook", "Twitter"]

const filtered = lookups.filter(lookup => filters.some(filter => filter.toLowerCase() != lookup.name.toLowerCase()));

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code gives those elements in result for which some of the values in `filters` is not equal to element's `name`. So for each element some of the name is not equal.

In other words you are using `!=` with `||` which will always return `true`.

```js
let a = "anything";
console.log(a !== "thing1" || a !== "thing2")
```

You need to use `every()` instead of `some()`.

```js
let lookups = [
{id: 1, name: "Twitter"},
{id: 2, name: "Facebook"},
{id: 3, name: "Linkedin"}
]

let filters = ["Facebook", "Twitter"]

const filtered = lookups.filter(lookup => filters.every(filter => filter.toLowerCase() !== lookup.name.toLowerCase()));

console.log(filtered)
```